# Passing CustomObject to Bottomsheetdialog

Tags: java, android

i implemented to my usermodel like this;
`public class UserModel implements Parcelable {`

I'm trying to sending my custom object to my BottomSheetDialog, and here is my code;

```
 ArrayList<UserModel> userModelArrayList = new ArrayList<UserModel>();
 BottomSheetDialog_modifed bottomSheetDialog_modifed = new BottomSheetDialog_modifed();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable("customObject", userModelArrayList);//i got problem here
    bottomSheetDialog_modifed.setArguments(bundle);
```

But i got error like that;

```
error: incompatible types: ArrayList<UserModel> cannot be converted to Parcelable
    bundle.putParcelable("customObject", userModelArrayList);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [Bundle.putParcelableArrayList(...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle#putParcelableArrayList(java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3C?%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E))